# $Tr((m+m^*)C) = 0 $ for every null trace $m$ implies $C = c \cdot I$

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

> Let $C \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ and suppose that $$Tr((m+m^*)C) = 0 $$ for every $m \in \mathfrak sl_n$ (i.e for every $n \times n$ matrix with null trace), with $*$ the transposition and conjugation. Then $C = c\cdot I$, i.e. $C$ is a scalar matrix.

The paper says that it's easy, but I can't see it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C \in \mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C})$. Then it follows from the fact that
$\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C})\cong \mathfrak{sl}(n, \mathbb{C})\oplus \mathbb{C}$, we see that
\begin{align}
C = cI+N
\end{align}
where $N$ is traceless. Next, observe
\begin{align}
(m+m^\ast)C = cm+cm^\ast + mN+m^\ast N
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}[(m+m^\ast)C] = \operatorname{Tr}[(m+m^\ast)N] =\operatorname{Tr}[mN]+\operatorname{Tr}[m^\ast N]= 0 
\end{align}
for all $m\in \mathfrak{sl}(n, \mathbb{C})$. In particular, if $m=N$, we see that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}[N^2]+\operatorname{Tr}[N^\ast N]=0
\end{align}
if and only if $N =0$.

Edit: Set $m = N$ then we have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}[N^2]+\operatorname{Tr}[N^\ast N]= 0.
\end{align}
Next, set $m = iN$, then we have that
\begin{align}
i\operatorname{Tr}[NN]-i\operatorname{Tr}[N^\ast N]= 0.
\end{align}
Hence $\operatorname{Tr}[N^\ast N]= \pm \operatorname{Tr}[N^2]$ which means $\operatorname{Tr}[N^\ast N]=0$.

Comment: Why is tha last implication true?

Comment: Consider the Jordan decomposition, then what you have is $\sum^N_{i=1} (\lambda_i^2+|\lambda_i|^2) = 2\sum^N_{i=1}\operatorname{Re}(\lambda_i)\lambda_i= 0$

Comment: I think that the diagonal matrix $(i,-i)$ is a counterexample!

Comment: Take that matrix and multiply by $i$, i.e. $iN$ which is still traceless, then plug it into $\operatorname{Tr}[m N]+\operatorname{Tr}[m^* N]=0$ and you will get a contradiction. So the diagonal matrix $(i, -i)$ can't be a counterexample.

Comment: You get a $-1$ in the second summand, so the equation is not the same.

Comment: I have edited my post. I hope the expanded version helps.

Comment: Thank! I trust this proof. I still can't see why the diagonal matrix is not a counterexample. xD

Comment: Ok I got the problem. This last version is even more elegant! Thank!